# yamba timeline.db not created

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am reading the book 'Learning Android' , currently the Database chapter

I have done everything as mentioned in the book, but I am unable to find the file 'timeline.db' in data/data in the file explorer,I am unable to find where I went wrong.(the app does not return any errors and it successfully posts the status messages)

Any info would be helpful.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you you are testing on a real device?

You can't see the content of `data/data` on real device due to security. If you want to see it you can test on `AVD`

Comment: Hi Mohsin, I have tried using the emulator too, but neither the file explore shoes the databases folder in the yamba package(com.marakana.yamba). I have even tried to find it using the command line 'ls /data/data/com.marakana.yamba/
databases/timeline.db'   , It says, no such file or directory

Comment: Hi , I found the issue, it was my mistake, I forgot to start the service in which the db was being created, now its working fine, many thanks for your time